# Next.js dynamic route - 404 on page reload or direct call of the dynamic route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nuxt.js, next.js

I use [NextJS](https://nextjs.org/) version 9.1.3.

and I have dynamic routing with an exportpathmap.

That is the dynamic route component:

```js
import { Spin, Icon } from 'antd';
import { Component } from 'react';
import getLocks from '../../data/helper/getLocks';
import PageTemplate from '../../components/PageTemplate';
import RenderLock from '../../components/RenderLock';

const antIcon = <Icon type="loading" style={{ fontSize: 24 }} spin />;

class lockdetails extends Component {

  static async getInitialProps({ query }) {
    const lockToReturn = getLocks().find((el) => el.id === query.lockID);
    return { lock: lockToReturn };
  }

  render() {
    const { lock } = this.props;

    return lock ? (
      <PageTemplate>
        <div
          style={{
            margin: '0 auto',
            marginBottom: 20,
            marginTop: 20,
          }}
        >
          <RenderLock lock={lock} />
        </div>
      </PageTemplate>
    ) : <Spin indicator={antIcon} />;
  }
}
export default lockdetails;
```

It works as such (if I use a `<Link>` to it, but If I

- reload the page I always get a 404 error
- call a dynamic uri in the browser like https://mywebsite.com/details/1/ I also get a 404 error.

As I said, if I click on a  to this route, it works perfectly. This shows that the custom routes are correct.

**What am I doing wrong ?**

Comment: When using next.js, your folder structure is quite important. Could you share the  folder structure inside the pages folder.

Comment: @Jurrian it is pages => lockdetails => [lockID].js